# Sort a Dictionary using LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, sorting

I have a

```
Dim carsDic as Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Dictionary<string, int> carsDic;
```

This is the list of Car Codes(string) and their Time(Integer, in minutes);

I want to sort the cars by time, then by code, and return the looser(higher time, upper code).

How can I use LINQ for this? (VB.NET!!, C#?!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var loser = carsDic.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                   .ThenByDescending(x => x.Key).First();
```

Comment: mine is a bit less letters :)

Answer (score 2):

`carsDic.OrderBy(cd => cd.Value).ThenBy(cd => cd.Key).Last()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var deadLastCar = carsDic.OrderByDescending(e => e.Value).ThenByDescending (e => e.Key).First();
```

Comment: It is not the *best* car, really, I want ))

Comment: Edited for being not the best car. ;)

Comment: ) This really should be the *worstCar* )

Comment: Racing simulation kind of thing, and you want the car that ended up last? =)

Comment: In the real application I have a different meaning of that values, here is just like this for the clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I 'm not going to provide a ready-made answer.

The easiest (most straightforward) approach would be to get all the information into a `List<Something>`, where `Something` is a class that has properties for both `Code` and `Time`. It could be an anonymous type (think `select new { Code = "X", Time = 0 }`), or a Tuple` or your own class.

You can then try sorting the `List` as per your requirements.

Try to work out how the above might be implemented, and edit the question if you need help with something more specific in the process.